# Castle DynamicProxy: Get unproxied object

Tags: .net, castle-dynamicproxy

I'm using Castle DynamicProxy to add an interceptor to my types.
Now I need to get the underlying base type (NOT the proxy itself).

I found a few hints on SO that suggested to use the ProxyUtil class like this:

```
object realInstance = ProxyUtil.GetUnproxiedInstance(proxyInstance);
```

This does not seem to work as

```
bool isProxy = ProxyUtil.IsProxy(realInstance);
```

is always true.

I also tried using the following code snippet, which is essentially what ProxyUtil is doing:

```
var accessor = proxyInstance as IProxyTargetAccessor;
var realInstance = accessor.DynProxyGetTarget();
```

with the same results, realInstance is still a proxy.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 9):

This question is a little old but hopefully my solution (which relies on .NET 4+) will help someone.

Having created a proxy as follows:

```
ProxyGenerator generator = new ProxyGenerator();
MyClass proxy = generator.CreateClassProxyWithTarget(underlying, new MyInterceptor(this));
```

I have been able to get the underlying target with the following method:

```
internal static TType UnwrapProxy<TType>(TType proxy)
{
    if (!ProxyUtil.IsProxy(proxy))
        return proxy;

    try
    {
        dynamic dynamicProxy = proxy;
        return dynamicProxy.__target;
    }
    catch (RuntimeBinderException)
    {
        return proxy;
    }
}
```

It relies on the internal implementation of Castle - i.e. that the generated proxy has a __target member. It is nice and self contained though and backed up with a unit test or two, we should catch any changes should a later version of Castle break this. This is using v3.2.0.0 of Castle.

Comment: `dynamic` for the win here. Beats trying to reflect into it. That was epic fail.

Comment: As of writing - i.e. 14 April 2019 - the code in this answer results in `'Castle.Proxies.IXeroServiceProxy.__target' is inaccessible due to its protection level`. I won't downvote as it is possible that it may have worked back then with a different version of both `dynamic` implementation as well as class `DynamicProxy`.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't have an `invocation` object available, or if you observe `'Castle.Proxies.IXeroServiceProxy.__target' is inaccessible due to its protection level` when trying **@s1mm0t**'s answer, you can try the following code which uses reflection instead of `dynamic`:

```
public static T UnwrapProxy<T>(T proxy) {
   if(!ProxyUtil.IsProxy(proxy)) {
      return proxy;
   }
   try {
      const System.Reflection.BindingFlags flags = System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance;
      var proxyType = proxy.GetType();
      var instanceField = proxyType.GetField("__target", flags);
      var fieldValue = instanceField.GetValue(proxy);
      return (T) fieldValue;
   }
   catch(RuntimeBinderException) {
      return proxy;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I simply use an interface like this

```
public interface IMarker
{
  Type ActualType { get; }
}
```

add it to my proxy and intercept it:

```
public class MyInterceptor<T> : IInterceptor
```

...

```
if (invocation.Method.DeclaringType == typeof(IMarker))
{
  if (invocation.Method.Name.Equals("get_ActualType"))
  {
    invocation.ReturnValue = typeof(T);
    return;
  }
}
```

So in the end i only have to check

```
if( obj is IMarker ) 
  Type t = (obj as IMarker).ActualType`
```

Maybe there are better options to do it, but it works and keeps my code clean from castle references.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are building an inheritance-based proxy (`generator.CreateClassProxy<MyClass>()`) the proxy **is** the target.

Comment: I'm using `CreateClassProxyWithTarget<MyClass>(instance, interceptor)` to create the proxy.
The problem is with NHibernate failing because it thinks it should map the proxy, and not the target.