# Moqing GetEnumerable fails when casting target to IEnumerable

Tags: c#, moq, ienumerable

I'm trying to mock a [Visual Studio CommandBars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.commandbars.commandbars.aspx) instance. CommandBars implements the non-generic IEnumerable interface. To be able to iterate over the mock, I set up GetEnumerable(). Strangely, this only works if I access the mock.Object as an instance of CommandBars. If I cast is to IEnumerable (as it happens implicitly when using Linq methods) GetEnumerable() suddenly returns null. Can someone explain this behavior?

```
var mockCommandBars = new Mock<CommandBars>();
IEnumerable bars = new List<CommandBar>();
mockCommandBars.Setup(cb => cb.GetEnumerator()).Returns(bars.GetEnumerator);

var cbs = mockCommandBars.Object;
var cbs1 = cbs.GetEnumerator();  // returns instance
var ecbs = (IEnumerable) cbs;
var cbs2 = ecbs.GetEnumerator(); // returns null!
```

Edit: I'm using Moq 4.2.1402.2112

Comment: Which moq version are you using? Can you post your `CommandBars` class especially your `GetEnumerator` implementation?

Comment: @nemesv http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.commandbars.commandbars.aspx

Comment: @nemesv I'm using Moq 4.2 (see updated question)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By examining the actual type of

```
 var cbs = mockCommandBars.Object;
```

at runtime, it appears that cbs has been wrapped as:

```
 cbs    {Castle.Proxies.CommandBarsProxy}
```

And that the cast to `IEnumerable` interferes with the proxy's behaviour.

You might be able to use the helper method from this [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19175806/314291), to wire access to the proxy's `__target` property, e.g.

```
var cbs2 = UnwrapProxy<IEnumerator>(cbs.GetEnumerator());
```

where

```
  internal static TType UnwrapProxy<TType>(TType proxy)
  {
     try
     {
        dynamic dynamicProxy = proxy;
        return dynamicProxy.__target;
     }
     catch (RuntimeBinderException)
     {
        return proxy;
     }
  }
```

**Edit**

[From Here](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/issues/22) it became clear that the setup wasn't being performed on the underlying `_CommandBars.IEnumerable` interface

You can change the setup explicitly:

```
     var cbs = mockCommandBars.As<_CommandBars>().As<IEnumerable>();
     cbs.Setup(cb => cb.GetEnumerator()).Returns(bars.GetEnumerator());

     var ecbs = (IEnumerable)cbs.Object; // The cast is now redundant.
     var cbs2 = ecbs.GetEnumerator();
```

---

If you want to keep a single mock variable to pass around, you can set it up like this.

```
var mockCommandBars = new Mock<CommandBars>();
mockCommandBars.Setup(cb => cb.GetEnumerator()).Returns(bars.GetEnumerator);
mockCommandBars.As<IEnumerable>().Setup(cb => cb.GetEnumerator()).Returns(bars.GetEnumerator);
```

This tells Moq that the Mock implements both interfaces, and defines `GetEnumerator` for both independently.

Comment: Thank you so much! This actually saved my life ;) I already figured that it had something to do with the typing, but it would have taken me at least a 100 years to figure that one out...

Comment: Also, note to self - if a method on a mock is ever returning null, first place to start is by enabling `MockBehavior.Strict` - saves much time :)