# Castle dynamic proxy object to original object convertion

Tags: c#, castle, castle-dynamicproxy, dynamic-proxy

```
 ProxyGenerator generator = new ProxyGenerator();
 var interceptor = new StandardInterceptor();
 MyInterfaceImpl test = (MyInterfaceImpl)generator.CreateClassProxy(typeof(MyInterfaceImpl), interceptor);
```

In above example, `test` object is proxy object, assume it is created by 3rd party.

I am not able to pass to WCF operation contract accepting `MyInterfaceImpl` parameter as its type is not `MyInterfaceImpl` but it is `MyInterfaceImplProxy`.

How can we convert `test` object to `MyInterfaceImpl` type? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Just cast it to IProxyTargetAccessor and you should be good to go. See https://github.com/castleproject/Core/blob/master/src/Castle.Core/DynamicProxy/IProxyTargetAccessor.cs

Comment: Even now when I know the answer I'm unable to duckduck/google it in Castle documentation - a little bit of shame on awesome project!

Answer (score 2):

I have found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082911/castle-dynamicproxy-get-unproxied-object).

```
internal static TType UnwrapProxy<TType>(TType proxy)
{
    if (!ProxyUtil.IsProxy(proxy))
        return proxy;

    try
    {
        dynamic dynamicProxy = proxy;
        return dynamicProxy.__target;
    }
    catch (RuntimeBinderException)
    {
        return proxy;
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case I needed dynamicProxy.__interceptors