# How to get unproxied object in EF CORE

Tags: castle-dynamicproxy, ef-core-2.2

With each EF version there was a different way to get an underlying object for a proxy. None of the old tricks work using EF core 2.2. I referenced Castle.Core which EF uses and called ProxyUtil.GetUnproxiedInstance but that just returns the proxy again as already noted in below article. NONE of the suggestions there work. NOTE ! I need the instance, not the type which I can easily get via BaseType.

[Similar question with no working solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082911/castle-dynamicproxy-get-unproxied-object)